# Microsoft Access 97 columnar form view with multiple results on screen

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working in a old project, I'm using Access 97 to edit an access form that manage some forms view and queries. I'm new to Access, I have seen the templates that come with this old software and the "columnar" maybe it's what I'm searching. By default a query that returns 5 results will render as a single view (with single record content inside) that can be "scrolled" with an arrow. Click the next button refresh content of the view with the next record's content.

My question is: Is it possible to show in an unique view all the results of the query? In this case, I can see in columnar style, 5 results together?

EDIT

This is an example of columnar form:
[image]

What i wanna achive is a "bigger view" that shows me all the employees in my db at the same time. So in my case 5 employees formatted in the that way.

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change this form's Default View to "continuous forms".

At the moment your form is probably set up so that it has some table holding your employee data...

[image]

...bound to the form's Record Source property:

[image]

Then the Default View property for the form has been set to "Single Form":

[image]

This results in the form displaying just 1 record at a time from its record source:

[image]

You'll want to change the Default View to "continuous forms" in order to have the form show all the records at the same time from its record source:

[image]

Doing so should then result in something like this:

[image]

...might look a bit weird as all controls placed in the "detail" section of your form will get repeated for each record, hence why the fields appear in the tab control on every record.

I'm using Access 2013, so these things may look a bit different in Access 97... but essentially this can all be done in Design View of the form, selecting the form and then changing the properties mentioned on the form's Property Sheet.